# How do i use docker-compose to allow for 2 containers to share a .sock file correctly in this example?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am working on my AWS EC2 instance, and now dockerising my applicaiton to get it ready for prod. I have a Django api for the backend and React frontend. The aim is to use gunicorn for the backend to serve the api and nginx to serve the react static files. I have got 2 docker files one for the backend and one for the frontend. The backend is working with gunicorn in the docker and also waorks with docker-compose.

I have been struggling with the frontend one. The docker itself will run with npm start(not with nginx), however refuses to work with docker-compose, could you please advise based on the code below what I need to correct? (as I was also writing this post I found that the docker copose for the frontend by itself does not end up launching)

After this I will try to get get it working with nginx again so won't be using npm start in prod.

Additionally, I would like to know how I can share the .sock file created by gunicorn to be able to be used by nginx in the 2 separate dockers. If this is not the correct way to connect my frontend and backend, please advise the best approach as it would be highly appreciated.

I have tried:
- a variety of additons and changes to the docker compose including adding a depends_on to the frontend servcie to depend on the backend.
- a combination of different solutions to have the same network and volumes and don't think it has helped in anyway yet.

output in terminal:

```sh
(project) ubuntu@XXXXXXXXXXX:~/django-react-app$ docker-compose up
Starting django-react-app_frontend_1 ... done
Starting django-react-app_backend_1  ... done
Attaching to django-react-app_frontend_1, django-react-app_backend_1
backend_1   | [2019-06-08 16:04:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
backend_1   | [2019-06-08 16:04:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.                               0:8000 (1)
backend_1   | [2019-06-08 16:04:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
backend_1   | [2019-06-08 16:04:51 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
backend_1   | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: U                               serWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in orde                               r to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instea                               d. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-f                               rom-pypi>.
backend_1   |   """)
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:

  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: frontend_docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - codevolume:/code
    networks:
      - backend

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend_docker
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - codevolume:/code
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  codevolume: 
# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  backend:
```

frontend_dockerfile

```
FROM node:11.15

USER root

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update -y && \
 apt-get install -y nginx && \
 apt-get clean && \
 mkdir /code/ && \
 rm -rf /tmp/*

WORKDIR /code

COPY source/frontend/ /code/

RUN npm install && \
 npm cache clear --force && \
 rm -rf /tmp/*

RUN npm run-script build && \
 rm -rf /tmp/*

#will only be using one of these with nginx and removing the other once i resolve this stackoverflow issue :)
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 3000

COPY configs/nginx.conf /tmp/

RUN mv /tmp/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/myreactfrontend && \
 ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myreactfrontend /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

#will ideally be switching to nginx afterward, may even look into multi stage builds if people think this would be recommended
#ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "npm start"]
```

Below file is working fine so so shouldnt need editing, I'm providng the file so it makes sense in the context.

backend_docker

```
FROM python:3

USER root

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements/base.txt /code/

COPY source/backend/ /code/

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mydjangoapi.settings.base

RUN pip install -r base.txt && \
 python manage.py makemigrations && \
 python manage.py migrate

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 mydjangoapi.wsgi"]
```

Comment: If you manually build and run the front end container, does it work (using docker build)? After executing `docker-compose up` does the container continue to run or does it immediately power off (`docker ps -a`)? You can try to grab logs from the front end to see if the issue is internal to it- `docker logs -f container-name` (replace `container-name` with the name of the container)..

Comment: yes it does work when I use it without docker-compose. Also, (correct or advise me if I am wrong) I don't think I can get the logs for it when running docker-compose as in my terminal all I see is the output I have attached above. I can't run another command after it or so as it seems it doesnt start and is still running. I have even waited for it for 10 minutes but had no luck. Note: the container takes less than a minute to get up and running.

Comment: You have to use `docker-compose up -d` if you want to let the containers run in the background (aka as a daemon, hence `-d`), so you can access your console again.  After you run that command, run `docker ps -a` to see if the container automatically stops or if it is still running - after that, try `docker logs -f your-container-name` to check logs (you will need to hit `CTRL+C` to break out of the `docker logs -f` command... Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Cheers for that! hadn't got to the point of running docker-compose in detached mode yet. The containers are both running however, the there is literally nothing in the docker logs for the frontend container. any other pointers?

Comment: So is the issue on the frontend just that after starting it, you are unable to access it?

Comment: I cannot acces it via browser, and the logs should contain the basic node react prompt that occurs when launching the server via `npm start` however via docker compose launching it, the container does not seem to be outputting this

Comment: What command are you using to run it without `docker-compose`?  It's odd nothing is in the logs... You can try running your own commands from inside the container by running: `docker exec -it your-container-name /bin/bash` then you should see something like this on the console: `user@c12c64e63362:/app# ` - you are now inside the container and can run any command you wish.. Try to run `npm start` to see what happens..

Comment: When not using docker compose, with the frontend_dockerfile above build with tag 'frontend', i do this:  docker run -d -p 3000:3000 frontend`
my docker logs are as follows to show it is workgin correctly:
`

> frontend@0.1.0 start /code
> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/Notification.jsx
  Line 1:  'React' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

`

Comment: I also just noticed in the docker ps when doing `docker-compose up -d`, that it seems the container is not using the correct entrypoint I have given it? it is trygin to use nginx instead of npm start, any idea why this is the case?

`d093f0d2c310        myproject_frontend      "/bin/bash -c 'nginx…"   About an hour ago   Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp........`

Comment: i did `docker-compose build` to fix the issue, and then foudn the case of the error. Now i beleive the issue is regarding volumes. How can I share the volume between the two containers? or am i going away from the right track?

Comment: Ah man I can't believe 'docker-compose build' didn't cross my mind =/  I'm glad you got the build part working! So why exactly are you needing to share volumes? Are you wanting to gather data on your front end from your back end this way? That will not work - you need to run them separately and query the API as you would any API - React will be running in the browser, not on the actual container..

Comment: so gunicorn makes a .sock file which from my understanding that I have to connect the nginx to. Previously when running just a full django website(without docker), it runs the django part with gunicorn and then nginx pointing the proxy as so:
`
location / {
  include proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://unix:/code/boasyapp.sock;
 }
`

do you not recommend this? and just have the ip for the react server set to 0.0.0.0? or should I do something else entirely? Sadly, I have not found any documentation to use docker with django and react in prod anywhere over the past 3 weeks and need help

Comment: I mostly have Vue and Node experience - I just started getting into React about a month ago and have yet to mess around dockerizing it. In my Vue apps I run a node backend API but as far as the containers are concerned, they are unrelated "machines". I have no Django experience so I'm not sure how that works in a container.  I would assume you run them unrelated.

Comment: I am also not familiar with gunicorn. On each container of mine I run NGINX to serve the resource, whether an API or Vue app. In front of those containers I run (containerized) Traefik as a reverse proxy. On Traefik I have to set up a .sock network so it can route to each container behind it. My containers do not share a .sock connection but they are able to communicate over the internal "LAN". Hope this helps.

Comment: That is useful to know! do you have recommended documentation or a tutorial you usually follow? I would be keen to look into it as it may still help me resolve my upcoming problems :)

Comment: At the beginning, instead of Traefik, I used an NGINX fork (by jwilder) to act as my reverse proxy... It was much easier to configure and get a grasp of the concept(s) at hand. I would recommend going that route.. Unfortunately, I did not follow any particular guide for this - it actually took me around a week and a half to learn everything.. I used a number of misc articles from around the web.. [This](https://romaincauquil.fr/code/2017/05/29/easy-https-on-vps-with-docker/) article may help, although it uses Express server side, it has a React front end...

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) the reverse proxy I used.. I wish I could be of more help, but unfortunately this is one of those things that is best learned by doing - which isn't meant to sound crass.. There are a lot of variables at play, and our scenarios are most likely different at a detailed level.  The 'thousand foot view' I have provided should be a good starting point for your research and testing.  Although, if you come across any issues or struggle with anything specific just let me know and I'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the fix for this was running `docker-compose build` due to the fact OP is building the containers via a `dockerfile` inside of the `docker-compose.yml` file, and not just 'turning images on' via `docker-compose`.